# Stuck at installing Google Chrome on a remote Debian 11 bullseye using SSH

Tags: debian, ssh, chrome

I'm trying to install Google Chrome on a VPS I have.

VPS has `Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)` on it.

I use `ssh root@ip` to connect. And I run these commands:

```
apt-get update 
apt upgrade
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb -O chrome
dpkg -i chrome
```

But I see these errors:

```
(Reading database ... 73725 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack chrome ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (107.0.5304.110-1) over (107.0.5304.110-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on fonts-liberation; however:
  Package fonts-liberation is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libnspr4 (>= 2:4.9-2~); however:
  Package libnspr4 is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libnss3 (>= 2:3.26); however:
  Package libnss3 is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on xdg-utils (>= 1.0.2); however:
  Package xdg-utils is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.69) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
```

And when I try to install `fonts-liberation` I see these errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libnspr4 (>= 2:4.9-2~) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.26) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: xdg-utils (>= 1.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: libu2f-udev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I did not try `--fix-broken` since I fear breaking stuff on this VPS.

How can I install Google Chrome on a Debian 11 bullseye, safely?

**Update**
This is the output of `apt policy`:

```
root@3rag:~# apt policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye/stable amd64 Packages
     release o=Docker,a=bullseye,l=Docker CE,c=stable,b=amd64
     origin download.docker.com
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=11,o=Debian,a=stable-security,n=bullseye-security,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://debian.mirror.serveriai.lt/debian bullseye/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=11.5,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bullseye,l=Debian,c=non-free,b=amd64
     origin debian.mirror.serveriai.lt
 500 http://debian.mirror.serveriai.lt/debian bullseye/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=11.5,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bullseye,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin debian.mirror.serveriai.lt
 500 http://debian.mirror.serveriai.lt/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
     release v=11.5,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bullseye,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin debian.mirror.serveriai.lt
Pinned packages:
root@3rag:~#
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dpkg` only handles the individual packages it’s given, it doesn’t know how to resolve dependencies; thus when you ran `dpkg -i chrome`, it was able to determine that a number of dependencies weren’t satisfied, but it couldn’t satisfy them itself. It still installed the Chrome package, but left it unconfigured.

This is what leads to the mention in `apt`’s subsequent output:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
```

Doing just that (`apt install -f` as root, which is the same as `apt --fix-broken install`) installs missing packages to resolve installed packages’ dependencies.

To avoid this in future, you can use `apt` directly to install a downloaded package, by giving it a path to the package:

```
apt install ./chrome
```

or

```
apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

without renaming the downloaded file.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you can safely run the fix broken install. Worst case it will update packages and you will have to revert. You can find out what it updated/fixed in the /var/log/apt/history.log, including version numbers.

[Disclaimer]
It's open source, YMMV.

Comment: Google Chrome *isn’t* open source.

Comment: @JdeHaan, thank you for sharing your experience. I'll do that as the last option.

Comment: *Chromium* is open source.